# Cordova Local Storage Android 5 S4

Tags: android, cordova, galaxy

I have programmed an App which is sending an localStorage Object with Ajax to my Server with a PHP-Program. That is doing something with the Data and it will send an answer back. 
Connection is perfect on the S4 but it looks like Server isnt doing anything with the sended LocalStorage.
Every Device (Pc, S3 mini(Android 4.2), Tab2 Tablet(Android 5)) works right, only the S4 doesnt?
Any ideas?

Comment: As this you storing and reading the data found in the localStorage?

Comment: Yes Im storing it and reading it than.

Comment: But how? can you provide the code?

Comment: localStorage.setItem("email", anmemail);

Comment: Its working fine just the S4 dont works

Comment: What version of javascript / jquery is using? Make sure it's the last! , also that of Cordova, which version are you using? Many saw this problem in Cordova 2.6